# FTP connection failing when runing SSIS package with SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is fully functional that generates files and places them on to my ftp server. I have a connection manager for my FTP server and have the ftp server details and credentials are saved in the manager. The connect is succesfull when testing the connection

But when I run the job form the SQL Server Agent I get this error

> Source: Connection manager "FTP"     Description: An error occurred in
>   the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The password
>   was not allowed

Comment: How do you have the job defined? Where is the SSIS package stored? What is the package protection level in this FTP package?

Comment: What do you mean by your first question?

I did not create the package and the person who did is no longer around so I'm trying to figure this out. The protection level is encrypted

I use this command in SQL Server Agent
dtexec.exe /FILE "D:\SSIS\Deploy\SSIS\package.dtsx"  /DECRYPT x3

I just took over and I'm told that the job used to work but the ftp server had to be changed. I updated the FTP credentials and server in the FTP connection manager in the package and that is where this started where the package works from SSIS but when running from SQL Agent I get ftp error